# Windows 2012 DHCP Failover: Scope refuses failover config Error: 20044

Tags: windows, dhcp

I have a scope configured on a Windows 2012 DHCP server (primary in a hot standby config) with two Cisco Vendor class options.  I've added the Vendor class options, identically, to the standby server.

When I configure failover for the scope I get "Configure failover failed.  Error: 20044.  The class name being used is unknown or incorrect."

Any idea of how to troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've set the option at the level you want; meaning either scope or server, but not both.  I've seen instances where setting the same setting at both levels can cause issues.  Try setting it at the server level first.

Let me know.